# How to change jQuery inputmask mask based on dropdown context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm presently using [jQuery inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) for the following effect:
[image]

It's fairly simple for US & Canada phone number formatting using something like:

```
$("#user_phone").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "(999) 999-9999" });
```

I would, however, like to change this formatting context based on the "Country code" dropdown such that when it is United Kingdom, it uses another mask, etc.  How would I implement this such that the mask will change context based on dropdown in js/jQuery?

Here's an example of the working source as it is now: http://jsfiddle.net/j9aNh/1/

UPDATE: Okay, I think I've got it working satisfactorily now and would appreciate any advice in terms of drying this up properly: http://jsfiddle.net/j9aNh/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if that what you are looking for but it could be as simple as that I think.

```
$('select').change(function() {

var country=$(this).val() //or if you want to get text you may use var country=$(this).text()
 var maskuse;
if(country=='USA')
{
maskuse="(999) 999-9999";


}
if(country=='Canada')
{

maskuse="(999) 999-9999";

}
/// and soon changing mask for a country 

$("#user_phone").inputmask("mask", { "mask": maskuse });

});
```

Comment: Added a little more info up above.  Thanks for your input!  I need to set the default mask also before setting based on `change`.  What function would I use there?

Comment: Actually, I think I've got it now.  I realize it's not dry and probably not optimal, so I'm open to any input on the source.

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for [Selection of an input mask for a phone number](http://andr-04.github.io/inputmask-multi/en.html), use [inputmask-multi](https://github.com/andr-04/inputmask-multi)