# How to debug user entry issues in JavaScript with WebKit developer tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, webkit

I have an issue where input is being doubled, tripled, quadrupled, etc. on user input after changing a select dropdown multiple times.  Here's a small video showing my dilemma and posing the question: http://screencast.com/t/7Gb01nGe787p

Essentially the question is how to debug properly given circumstances like this?

Comment: Do you have any code to post as well? It would be useful to see if you are using what(if any) ui widgets, or anything like that.

Comment: Well, in this case the code is fairly embedded into an app and I'll have to yank it out.  The problem is that when I yank it out, this section works fine and the error goes away, so I really have to have it in full context to see it and at this time I simply can't post the app here. I am using jQuery and the [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask), however as noted, when these are alone contextually, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think how you debug depends heavily on how your code is structured.

If you are using widgets(jquery UI stuff, plugins, external libraries etc) you can always search around and see if its a known bug/issue. Aside from that, checking configurations(I've been burned by config's not being correct several times) can be helpful. Also check for conflicting code, such as events you may have defined that could interfere with the widgets behavior. Manipulating objects in the webkit console is particularly useful for this, since you can more easily find out in what cases your code will work, and in what cases it will not, without necessarily having to rely on manipulating the UI.

If you are not using something other people wrote, then debugging is a little easier in my opinion. For me, it really comes down to narrowing the scope of where I am looking. If you have any events related to your issue(onKeyUp or something), log it. Console.log can go a long way, especially when dealing with the state of UI, and so can breakpoints. I'm not sure if this is necessarily the best way to do it, but I find it to be very useful in the right situation.

If you are really stuck, you can always get drastic and start removing pieces of your code. May not sound very nice, but if you are really stuck and cannot seem to find what section of code is being problematic it will at least give you an indicator of where to look. Again, not the prettiest solution, but it's saved me a lot of headaches on more than one occaision.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Had an idea.  I did post a WORKING version of this source earlier [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022589/how-to-change-jquery-inputmask-mask-based-on-dropdown-context).  I thought perhaps that would give you a little context, although there's no error in the mix in that one per se.  Indeed it is obviously coming from some other interaction.  Having it increment to repeat twice on the 2nd change, thrice on the third change, etc. leads me to believe something is loading an additional time on each select change, but it's a real stinker to hunt down right now.